# I want to execute code in C# after a specific function call in CAPL code

Tags: c#, synchronization, delay, capl

My C# code starts and executes the CAPL code but when any specific function eg. abc(int a) is called internally by CAPL then I want to send data of parameter "a" in C# and perform calculation and send result back to same function "abc" and CAPL code should resume its execution from abc() as this function returns a value and that value should be from my calculated C# code.

My issues:

1. I dont know when abc function is called (abc is just en example actual function is predefined) So, want to know when this function is called and get parameters in C#.
2. I tried by using "onchange" method in C# but onchange works after execution is completed of function "abc". So, this is not useful as synchronization is not maintained and CAPL returns a default value.
3. Tried using "timer" method but same issue of synchronization as CAPL is not stopping the execution it continues the execution till the timer.
4. Tried using While loop with timer but CAPL gets lagged out and CANeo stops working

I Hope sample code is not required as I just need a function

Comment: In other words, you want to call C# from CAPL. Is that correct? I.e. from wtihin the CAPL function `abc` you want to call C# code and continue `abc` with the return value of the C# function. Is that right?

Comment: Yes exactly thanks for simplifying it..

Answer (score 1):

Calling C# (or any other .NET) code is actually possible starting from CANoe version 12.0 SP3

Search for *.NET DLL* in CANoe's help for details.

Basically, you create a .NET function like

```
namespace ns {
  public class Clazz {
    public static Int32 Func(Int32 a) {
      ...
      return a;
    }
  }
}
```

It must be static, public and in a public class.
Only certain datatypes are allowed as parameters and return value.

The compiled .NET DLL has to be added to CANoe in the same way as a CAPL-DLL.

Calling the function from CAPL then looks like this:

```
retVal = ns::Clazz::Func(17);
```

---

If you have to use a CANoe version earlier than 12.0 SP3, you would have to create a CAPL DLL in C/C++ and call you C# code via CLI.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.. I understand this is one way but dll will not help in my case as the function in C# takes other inputs as well from user which will change as per the user.. 
So, basically I have created main application which is in of dotnet which uses caneo.
Can you help me is this situation ? Is there any way by using threading in CANeo. So that I can get values from func of caneo to C# via different thread, till then CANeo runs a loop will it gets thread with values and continue the main thread by stooping the loop. Or any other solution will also help.

Comment: @SamarthJanardhan That will not work. CANoe cannot _suspend_ a running CAPL function. The only exception is when using a test node, i.e. not a simulation node, but a node in the test setup using the test feature set. There you can use the methods like `testWaitFor...` to actually wait for en event, like user input. For your use case - if I understood it correctly - you most likely would have to split it up. I.e. trigger your C# code from CAPL and return immediately, so that CAPL can continue and later on trigger (a different) CAPL code from C#.